# Is symmetric matrix has nonzero eigen values or is Positive (semi-)definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, self-learning, symmetric-matrices

Let M be symmetric matrix. Its eigen values are 0 or real(but not complex)

$Mx = \lambda x$

taking transpose on both sides and multiplying by $Mx$ on both sides

$(Mx)^TMx = \lambda x^TMx, $

Let y = Mx then we have

$\lambda x^TMx = (Mx)^TMx = y^Ty$ --> this is nothing but squared sum. It means $y^Ty \geq 0$

It meaans $\lambda x^TMx \geq 0 \implies \lambda  \geq 0 , $ OR $x^TMx \geq 0$ which means symmetric matrix has either eigen values non-negative or positive semi-definite? May i know is this true? I was thinking of some other problem but got this which i do not know

In defination of positive (semi-)definiteness, there are 2 conditions

1. symmetric matrix
2. $x^TMx \geq 0$

Comment: Hint: consider $-I,$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Your statement is not true. In general $y^Ty$ is not a squared term you have to take the conjugate of the of $y^T$. For instance, take $y=(i)$ then $y^T=y$ gives us $y^Ty=-1$

Comment: Are we talking about real symmetric $M$? Presumably yes, given that you use the standard transpose rather than the conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the eigen values of symmetric matrices are real is the following:

$\lambda=\langle v,\lambda v\rangle= \langle v,Av\rangle=\overline{\langle Av,v\rangle}=\langle \lambda v,v\rangle=\overline{\lambda}$

Comment: Sir i never thought that there could be complex entries in y. Thanks for pointing it. So statement i made (in title ) is true only if M is real symmetric right?